# How can I play Mixcloud files in AVPlayer swift

Tags: swift, ios10, avplayer, mixcloud

I am trying to play mixcloud media file in AVPlayer, but player not playing the file. The observeValue key path status is saying AVPlayer is playing the media. But in reality it is not.I am using swift in ios10.

1. Anyone have experience in playing mixcloud files in AVPlayer
2. Can AVPlayer play Mixcloud audio?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get better answers for your questions